# How to run Angular-scenario runner tests with Angular1/2 hybrid app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

We have a big Angular 1.4 application. Our equally big set of E2E tests are written using Angular Scenario Runner (Yes, I know we should have used Protractor).

Now, we are trying to transition to Angular2, going through the ngUpgrade hybrid approach.

The issue is that the ngScenario tests are all failing due to bootstrapping issues. As, the bootstrapping is asynchronous for the upgradeAdapter, opposed to synchronous in Angular 1.

Please help as to what could be done ?